# How to convert a .h5 model to a .tflite and also get image labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am pretty new to Deep Learning, I have a custom dataset which is quite large, how do I convert the .h5 model to a .tflite model and also how do I generate all the labels without doing it manually?

Answer (score 0):

[From Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert?hl=fr)

#### Convert the model

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir) # path to the SavedModel directory
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```